# How to search folder in the file system and move it to the destination file system using ssis?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, ssis

I have some tables in SQL Server database, in each table there is a column that contain a ID number. For some each specific ID number our system application create a folder in the source file system, folder name is same as ID number, folder contain many sub-folder and files with different names. I have to select ID numbers from tables and need to search that ID number in the source file system as a folder name, if any ID number is match with a folder name then i need to copy the folder and all of its contain and need to paste it to the destination file system if the folder dose not exist in the destination. I may need your help to do this using ssis.

Comment: What have you tried? Does it need to be done in SSIS?

Comment: I think SSIS is the best to do this, I don't know if there any best solution, please let me know how to solve this.

Comment: You can do it in Powershell, VBScript, a C# console app, whatever. You need to manipulate a database and the file system. SSIS is good at database and OK at file system.

Answer (score 1):

The basic pattern is:

1. Using an [Execute SQL Task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/control-flow/execute-sql-task), store the required ids in an object variable.
2. Use a [Foreach Loop Container](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/control-flow/foreach-loop-container) to process each row, stored in your object variable.
3. Within the loop, use a [Script Task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/control-flow/script-task) or a [File System Task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/control-flow/file-system-task) to create a directory, for the current row.

Script tasks offer more flexibility than file system tasks but require an understanding of VB or C#.

You could use the [Execute Process Task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/control-flow/execute-process-task) if you are more comfortable working with batch/PowerShell scripts.

Comment: thanks for your help, in your mentioned point number 3, i don't need to create folder, folder is already in the source file system, i need to check the folder name, if folder name is match with ID number then i need to copy all of its contain and paste it to the destination file system. please help and give me the basic pattern to solve the issue.

Comment: Are the folders always located in the same place.  Example:  for ids `1001`, `1002` and `1003` the folders would be: `C:\MyFolder\1001`, `C:\MyFolder\1002` and `C:\MyFolder\1003`?

Comment: Yes, the folders always located in the same place. You did the right example.

Comment: Then I would follow the pattern above.  Step one should insert all sources and destinations into an object var.  Step two extracts current source and destination.  Step three copies source to destination.  If source always exists use a file system task, it's easier.  If not, use a script task.  This can check if a folder exists [using .Net](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory.exists(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: Thanks for your comments.